# How to disable TRIM on SSD(s) under Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, trim, fstrim

I rarely ever write anything (large) to SSDs on many machines of my own, an example could be the use of one laptop as a TV *viewer* only, another my mother's laptop, which she uses just for banking. (If it matters, I use Linux Mint on all machines.)

Therefore it comes as annoying the weekly TRIM, as it takes a rather long time. But how to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To check the status of TRIM timer

```
sudo systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

You would get something like this:

```
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Mon 2022-01-10 06:36:56 CET; 31min left
    Trigger: Mon 2022-01-17 00:00:00 CET; 6 days left
   Triggers: ● fstrim.service
       Docs: man:fstrim
```

---

### To disable the periodic TRIM (TRIM timer)

```
sudo systemctl disable fstrim.timer
```

After reboot, you will get the status as follows:

```
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● fstrim.service
       Docs: man:fstrim
```

---

### To manually invoke TRIM (on all mounted FS)

```
sudo fstrim --all
```

---

Further reading:

- [fstrim man page #1](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fstrim)
- [fstrim man page #2](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html)
- [Does SSD Trim actually increase the lifespan? (Quora)](https://www.quora.com/Does-SSD-Trim-actually-increase-the-lifespan)